# c# How to encode arabic characters to utf8?

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

i try to encode Arabic characters to utf8 as sample

```
string clientName="على";
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(clientName);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string clientNameArabic = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

but i think it is not correct
so, i need help

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to convert your string to `Windows-1256` charset. It's just:

```
// on server side(before sending as byte array)
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientName);

// on client side(after reciving byte array)
clientName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Also in most situation's(except when using very low-level IO, like network sockets, or binary file streams) you don't need to think about encoding conversion at all, because UTF-8 is default encoding that used in .NET high-level I/O operations.

---

To accomplish your weird task of converting normal Unicode string `على` to broken [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) with symbols like `Óèïåçäèðÿ` you should write your string using Arabic Windows Encoding(1256), then read it back using Western European Windows Encoding(1252) like this:

```
var source = "على";

var westernLatin = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);

var bytes = arabic.GetBytes(source);
var result = westernLatin.GetString(bytes); // Uáì
```

No need to use UTF-8 here.

Comment: result is : clientName is same before encoding

Comment: @Paradigm, yes, as it should. Or you expected something else?

Comment: i expected characters like Óèïåçäèðÿ

Comment: @Paradigm, ehm... for what purpose? Just for fun? Or to prank some client with "ah, it's weird characters on screen! your data is totally broken! pay us for repair!"?

Comment: @Paradigm, i updated answer with solution to your task.